# why print null string in android Logcat show nothing?

Tags: android, logcat

when I debug using a Log, however with a message of null string(not space just like "") by coincidence, and the results show nothing even no empty colorful logcat row, that is to say, if I want to execute Log.d(TAG, msg) but the string msg is a null character(msg.equals(""); it show nothing in DDMS , so I have to append some other characters as a mark to guarantee the log row to appear for check.
Is there other approach to handle this issue? Appriciate a lot

Comment: You mean an empty string. A null String would be a variable that's unassigned. But either way, what's the point of printing an empty string in logcat? Why not use logcat for its intended purpose, that is to give useful information for debugging your app?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's helpful to print something that describes what your String variable is supposed to mean, so why not do something like:

```
Log.d(TAG, "my message: " + msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is empty( eg: ""), it will not be logged as mentioned in documentation.
To see the string, you will have to concatenate it with some additional info like:

```
Log.d(TAG, "String value:"+message)
```